# Some errors with fabs in C

Tags: c++

I am writing the following function in c++:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mex.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "matrix.h"

void funnc(double *f, double *x, long n, long b, double lambda, double theta)
{
    long i;
    long j;
    double u,v,y,z,w;
    y = theta*lambda;
    w = lambda*lambda;
    z = 0.5*(theta+1.0)*w;

    u = 0.0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<b;j++)
        v = fabs(x[i][j]);
        if (v <= lambda)
            u += lambda*v;
        else if (v > y)
            u += z;
        else
            u += 0.5*(v*(2*y - v) - w)/(theta-1.0);
    }

    *f = u;
    return;
}
etc.
```

In fact, the compilation of the function is failed due the following error:

```
error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type 
error C2168: 'fabs' : too few actual parameters for intrinsic function
```

Please can someone correct my code?? I don't know a lot about C++.

Any help will be very appreciated!

Comment: You have a double-dereference, `x[i][j]` on a single-indirection variable. `x` is `double*`, not `double**` or `double (*)[N]`

Comment: Thank you for your answers :) Unfortunately it is my first day using language C.

Comment: You're not "using language c++", you're using C.

Comment: Thank you. In fact I am a lot confused by the difference between c and c++. I just wanted to correct this code. I am not interested to learn more about C language :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You gave just a pointer to your function. As I understand you want to get a 2D table. You should give double** x instead of double* x.

Answer (score 2):

Your `x` is of type `double*` so it's a 1D array: you can't call something as `x[i][j]`.

Comment: Thank you, yes double* is for 1D

Answer (score 2):

If you have sent address of first element of 2D array, then you have to do correct pointer math:

Not:

```
x[i][j]
```

Because it's a single pointer.
Assuming that `b` is width of the 2D array, you can do this:

`v = fabs(*(x+i*b+j));`